# Bug in overloaded execute method of TDBXCallback that accepts and returns a TObject

Tags: delphi, callback, datasnap

There's an overloaded version of the Execute function of the TDBXCallback calls in Data.DBXJSon that looks like this

```
function Execute(Arg: TObject): TObject; overload; virtual; abstract;
```

Which in my Datasnap client, I've implemented like this:

```
type
  ServerChannelCallBack = class(TDBXCallback)
  public
    function Execute(const Arg: TJSONValue): TJSONValue; overload; override; // this works!
    function Execute(Arg: TObject): TObject; overload; override; // this doesn't
  end;

function ServerChannelCallBack.Execute(Arg: TObject): TObject;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := TObject.Create; // is this correct?
  try
    if Arg is TStringList then
    begin
      FormClient.QueueLogMsg('ServerChannel', 'Got TStringList');
      for i := 0 to TStrings(Arg).Count - 1 do
        FormClient.QueueLogMsg('ServerChannel', TStringList(Arg)[i]);
    end;
  finally
  end;
end;
```

This is called from the Datasnap server like this:

```
procedure TFormServer.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sr: TStringList;
begin
  sr := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sr.Add('one');
    sr.Add('two');
    ServerContainer2.DSServer1.BroadcastObject('SERVERCHANNEL', sr);
  finally
    // sr 
  end;
end;
```

This is following on from an example in the video presented by Matt DeLong

[Heavyweight Callbacks with DataSnap - Part 1: Thick Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrweqUlENHU)

The callback works perfectly, but only exactly once! On the second call from the server (Button2Click), I get an AV in the client. It might be a bug in the DBX code. I don't know. I can't trace in there. Or perhaps I have initialized the Result from the ServerChannelCallBack.Execute incorrectly. Any assistance is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The callback is registered on the client like this:

```
        TFormClient = class(TForm)
          CMServerChannel: TDSClientCallbackChannelManager;
        ...
        private
          ServerChannelCBID: string;
        ...
       procedure TFormClient.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
       begin
          ServerChannelCBID := DateTimeToStr(now);
          CMServerChannel.RegisterCallback(
            ServerChannelCBID,
            ServerChannelCallback.Create
          );
        ...
```

Comment: Without having looked at the dbx code, I'd assume that the function is supposed to return the same object that was passed to it: Result := Arg; rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @dummzeuch I modified the code to do exactly that (Result :=Arg) but I got the same result. I think it's a bug, I must report to Quality Portal.

Comment: If I had posted the entire code, it would have obfuscated the question. Clearly people aren't using SO as much as they used to, simply because of people like you.

Comment: I appreciate that you spent a lot of time on this, but then you came back with this wierd attitude which I don't understand. Perhaps if I changed the title of the question to something more applicable you'd be more willing to accept it? What do you suggest?

Comment: Online misunderstandings are easy to stumble into, so no worries. I took your title to mean that you were interested generally in how to return an object from a DS server, but now I know otherwise. I wasn't intending a "wierd attitude", even after watching the linked video, I was none the wiser about how you are registering your callback, which your update now shows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm basing this answer on the DataSnap Server + Client projects which can be downloaded from inside Delphi Seattle using `File | Open from version control'

https://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/radstudiodemos/branches/RadStudio_XE/Delphi/DataSnap/CallbackChannels

that's mentioned here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41374.

The forms in both the server and client require a slight correction to get them to compile, name to add `JSon` to their Uses list.

On the server form, I've added the following:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sr: TStringList;
begin
  Inc(CallbackCount);   // A form variable
  sr := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sr.Add('Callback: ' + IntToStr(CallbackCount));
    sr.Add('two');
    ServerContainer1.DSServer1.BroadcastObject('ChannelOne', sr);
  finally
    // No need for sr.free
  end;
end;
```

(I'm using ChannelOne for consistency with the client)

and on the client I have:

```
function TCallbackClient.Execute(Arg: TObject): TObject;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
//  Result := TObject.Create; // is this correct?
  Result := TJSONTrue.Create;
  try
    if Arg is TStringList then
    begin
      QueueLogValue('Server: Got TStringList');
      for i := 0 to TStrings(Arg).Count - 1 do
        QueueLogValue('Server:' + TStringList(Arg)[i]);
    end;
  finally
  end;
end;
```

With those variations from the code you've shown in your q, the server and client run fine, and I can click the server button as many times as I like and neither the server nor any of the clients get "stuck".  So I think your problem must be specific to something in the code you are using, but at least the linked project gives you something to work from and compare with.

Btw, I changed the `TCallbackClient.Execute` return type to `TJSONTrue.Create` (same as the other override) because that's what it says in Marco Cantu's Delphi 2010 Handbook says it should return, admittedly in the context of a "lightweight" callback while a ServerMethod is executing: returning TJSONFalse tells the server to cancel the executing ServerMethod.  However, the callbacks from the server work equally well with the `TObject.Create` you used.

Comment: That was an excellent answer. Be aware that I am working in Delphi 10.1 update 2. So... I modified the source from the repository as you suggested, and the same client error occurs as in my own example code on the second click of the server's button1. "Project DBXClientChannels.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00450987: read of address 0x00011cb8'.

Comment: In that case, if I were you I would report it to Emba as a DataSnap bug that's crept in between Seattle and 10.1 update 2.  Shouldn't be hard for them to reproduce.  I've retracted my VTC btw.

Comment: I am actually grateful for you participation in this endevour. When there's an EMBT bug you bang your head against the proverbial wall endlessly. I wonder if EMBT know how much time-wasting their carelessness causes?

Comment: @nolaspeaker:  Personally, I find the fact that nothing has apparently been done to fix the demo more worrying than the fact that a bug has seemingly been introduced into the DS code; bugs happen.  Has nobody else noticed that it doesn't even compile any more?  Or maybe they have but Emba haven't done anything about it.

Comment: For myself, after updating from Seattle to Berlin, I was alarmed by the number of new issues. My own bug reports in Quality Portal stand as testament to this (Incidently my username of QP is not NolaSpeaker  - just in case you go looking for me there)